# Is it possible to send multiple RichEmbeds in a single message

Tags: discord, discord.js

In the documentation, it states that a `Message` can have an [array of Embeds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds).

This obviously makes one question if it's possible to send multiple `RichEmbed` with a single message.

The normal way to send an Embed is to use a [MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) Object, like this:

```
message.channel.send({embed: embedName});
```

Although this doesn't seem to allow for a multiple of RichEmbeds, does anyone know if it's possible to send multiple?

Comment: You can only accomplish this using webhooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Abz6is](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11159372/anu6is) pointed out, you can post multiple `RichEmbeds` at once by using a Webhook.

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WebhookMessageOptions) is the documentation for the `WebhookMessageOptions`.

Quick example:

```
message.channel.createWebhook('Webhook Name', message.author.displayAvatarURL)
.then(w => w.send({embeds: [
    new Discord.RichEmbed().setAuthor('Embed 1'),
    new Discord.RichEmbed().setAuthor('Embed 2'),
]}));
```

This works for up to 10 embeds.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! it is Possible to do this, by doing

```js
if(message.content.startswith(Anything)) {
message.channel.send({embed: embedName});
message.channel.send({embed: embedName});
}
```

Caltrop's Answer also Works.

Comment: Hmm, this is not exactly what was asked for. You are sending 2 different messages with 1 embed each, I asked for a singular message with multiple embeds attached.